# Scalar product question

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(\cdot,\cdot)$ be a scalar product on a finite dimensional vector space and let $0\ne v,w$ be two vectors of the same length, i.e. $(v,v)=(w,w)$.

Visually, it seams to me clear that the angle formed between $v$ and $w-v$ must be obtuse, i.e. that $(v,w-v)\le 0$.

How to prove this formally? (Or is this statement false?)

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\theta$ denote the angle between $v$ and $w$, then
$$
(v,w-v)=(v,w)-(v,v)=|v||w|\cos(\theta)-|v|^2=|v|^2(\cos(\theta)-1)\leq 0,
$$
because $|v|=\sqrt{(v,v)}=|w|$.